# How to make ViewBox stretch inside a Grid Cell with a ColumnSpan?

Tags: wpf, layout

I am creating a test WPF project (calculator) to test the implementation of command bindings and logging. The base layout is a grid. The display of the calculator is a TextBox spanning two columns and stretching to fill all available space. This works OK, but I want to resize the text in the display when the main form resizes using a ViewBox. I tried introducing the ViewBox in several ways but while the text in the display resizes allright the TextBox no longer stretches to fill all space.

How do I solve this? XAML below.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">M+</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">MR</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                Click="Button_Click">1</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
                Click="Button_Click">2</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2"
                Click="Button_Click">3</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"
                Click="Button_Click">4</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"
                Click="Button_Click">5</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3"
                Click="Button_Click">6</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
                Click="Button_Click">7</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4"
                Click="Button_Click">8</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4"
                Click="Button_Click">9</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="5"
                Click="Button_Click">0</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5"
                Click="Button_Click">.</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2">=</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3">+</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4">-</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3">x</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4">:</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">C</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1">CE</Button>
        <Viewbox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <Label >M</Label>
        </Viewbox>
        <!-- Display -->
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                 Text="{Binding CurrentValue}"/>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <TextBox Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Viewbox}, Path=ActualWidth}"    
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             Text="{Binding CurrentValue}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

That works for me.  Then my mate goes pfft! just do this

```
<Viewbox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
        <TextBox Width="100"     
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
         Text="{Binding CurrentValue}"/>
</Viewbox>
```

And wow that works alot better

Comment: Thank you. Your mate's answer is surprisingly the better one. However, any attempt to make the TextBox's height equal to the Buttons' causes the Text to shrink.

Comment: Just put your buttons in viewboxes as well if you worried about that.  Don't forget to give them a width though so the viewbox can scale them correctly